# Installing, enabling and disabling extensions returns "is not of type String"

Tags: upgrade

I have multiple issues with my extensions in CiviCRM version 5.53.0 using WordPress. Note that the database was migrated from a previous Drupal installation.

Whenever I install, enable or disable an extension, I get the following stack trace:

```
0   CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery('UPDATE `civicrm_…', Array, true)    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php:1619
1   CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery('UPDATE `civicrm_…', Array)  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/CustomOption.php:238
2   CRM_Core_BAO_CustomOption::updateValue(868, 'table')    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/OptionValue.php:145
3   CRM_Core_BAO_OptionValue::add(Array)    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/OptionValue.php:34
4   CRM_Core_BAO_OptionValue::create(Array) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/Traits/DAOActionTrait.php:170
5   Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOUpdateAction->write(Array) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/Traits/DAOActionTrait.php:141
6   Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOUpdateAction->writeObjects(Array)  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOUpdateAction.php:31
7   Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOUpdateAction->updateRecords(Array) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractUpdateAction.php:93
8   Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractUpdateAction->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php:69
9   Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOUpdateAction))  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:149
10  Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\DAOUpdateAction))  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php:234
11  Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute() /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:85
12  civicrm_api4('OptionValue', 'update', Array)    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php:257
13  CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->updateExistingEntity(Array)   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php:144
14  CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEntities(Array)  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php:112
15  CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcile()   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:417
16  CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches(true) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Manager.php:425
17  CRM_Extension_Manager->disable(Array)   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php:197
18  CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:573
19  CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144
20  CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), 'next', 'Next')   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43
21  CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), 'next')  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203
22  HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), 'next')    /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103
23  HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle('next') /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355
24  CRM_Core_Controller->run()  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:334
25  CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(64, null) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php:140
26  CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php:105
27  CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run(Array, null) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319
28  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
29  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
30  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199
31  CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke('')   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308
32  WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332
33  WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:517
34  do_action('toplevel_page_Ci…')  /home/WEBSITE/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:259
35  {main}
```

The error message below the stack trace is simply "is not of type String". The extension is installed, activated or disabled correctly, but since I am having other issues with these extensions, I wanted to bring this up and see if there is an underlying issue.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, this was related to faulty entries in `civicrm_managed`. I deleted the entries and reinstalled the related extension (which was SearchKit in my case), the extensions now update correctly and no errors appear when modifying them.

Comment: I had the same problem. I have:
- deleted all records in the `civicrm_managed` table
- executed the API `cv api4 managed.reconcile {}`
and now everything seems okay to me